# How to position text and social media icons on same line

Tags: html, css, position, icons, alignment

I am trying to align x2 social media icons at either side of some text on the footer of my one page website.

Here is an example of how I want it to display on desktop/wide screens.[Desktop/Wide Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUzja.jpg)

And here is an example of how I want it to display on mobile/narrow screens.
[Mobile/Narrower Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zabFv.jpg)

I have entered my code below that I have so far (currently without the Social Media Icons in)

P.S. my Social Media icons are saved as facebook.png and twitter.png

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', 'Arial', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 250%;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto;
}


p {
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.coming-soon {
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.autumn-2017 {
    color: #ccc; 
}

section p {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto 10px;
    font-size: 35%;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #333;
}

.contact-info {
    margin: 15px auto;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 35%;
}

a:link, 
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    transition: font-weight 0.2s;
}

a:hover, 
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="desctription" content="Web Design & Development">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="queries.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="resources/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            
            <div>
                <img src="iz-icon-logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
                <p><span class="coming-soon">coming soon.</span><span class="autumn-2017">&nbsp;autumn 2017.</span></p>
            </div>
            
        </header>
        <section>
            <div>
                <p>If you have a Web Design or Development enquiry,<br>please contact:</p>
                <p class="contact-info"><a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">hello@illusionzero.co.uk</a><br><a href="tel:07903490453">+44 (0) 7903 490453</a></p>
            </div>
            
        </section> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see what you've tried so far and where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and proper use of @media query and [order](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/) property:

You can check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltkv6qus/) to play with the browser size.

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  footer i{
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <i>icon one</i>
  <p>links</p>
  <i>icon two</i>
</footer>
```

Comment: You're answer is right but his case it wont work as he trying to achieve desktop view on a mobile with text as wide as the screen.

Comment: Have a look at the link he provided. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBtmv.jpg That text is almost same size as the screen, and he/she want to place two images on the either side of that.

Comment: The text (link in my case) is full screen on mobile... Try it on jsfiddle by changing the text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css position property

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', 'Arial', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 250%;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto;
}


p {
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.coming-soon {
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.autumn-2017 {
    color: #ccc; 
}

section p {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto 10px;
    font-size: 35%;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #333;
}

.contact-info {
    margin: 15px auto;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 35%;
}

a:link, 
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    transition: font-weight 0.2s;
}

a:hover, 
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ccc;
    font-weight: 500;
}


/* NEW CSS */

.footer-container{
   position:relative;
   padding:0 50px;
   text-align:center;
   max-width:300px; 
   margin:0 auto;
}

.ico{
   background-color:#333;
   display:inline-block;
   width:36px;
   height:36px;
   line-height:36px;
   font-size:12px;
   text-align:center;
   border-radius:36px;
   color:#FFF;
   
   position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-18px;
}

.fb{ left:0;  }
.tw{  right:0; }


@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .footer-container{ padding:0; }
   .ico{ position:static; margin-top:0px; }

}
```

```html
<header>
   <div>
      <img src="iz-icon-logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo" />
      <p>
         <span class="coming-soon">coming soon.</span><span class="autumn-2017">&nbsp;autumn 2017.</span>
      </p>
   </div>
</header>

<section>
   <div>
      <p>If you have a Web Design or Development enquiry,<br>please contact:</p>
      <div class="footer-container">
      <p class="contact-info">
         <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">hello@illusionzero.co.uk</a><br>
         <a href="tel:07903490453">+44 (0) 7903 490453</a> 
       </p>
      <span class="ico fb">Fb</span>
         <span class="ico tw">Tw</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cheers Mahmoud, I tried your code above and it worked when I did it in a brand new text file, however when I tried merging it with my own code, the icons wouldn't change to the smaller size of 42px as you were asking it to in the css and I couldn't get them to display at each side of my text. I have edited my original post above showing my code, and actual pictures of my website. If you could help further that would be great

Comment: with pleasure GTM1. if I understood correctly, you want to add the two icons of social networks next to the text in the footer, because I do not see the icons in your code